# SSRS Report Unable to get withing scope of the values in RowGroup. Only got values using Previous and current scope value

Tags: reporting-services

I already calculated a row(Add Total row) like  Gross profit within Group1(a,b,c,d,e) using Previous and current scope column group values. ex: Gross Profit = a - b.

Gross Profit = Previous(Sum(Fields!Trans_amount.Value)) - Sum(Fields!Trans_amount.Value) in Group1
Now, I want to get values for Net income like  Net income = a - b - c in Group1.  (OR)

Net income = Gross  Profit - c in Group1 (Using Gross Profit textbox values using Reportitems!textbox.value). but, values different.  Since Expression got new calculation)

Please help me.

Thanks Advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get a "running value decreasing total" value in your report. For example, it returns "a-b" first, then "a-b-c", "a-b-c-d", "a-b-c-d-e". Is my understanding correct? In Reporting Services, it doesn't have any built-in function to achieve this goal. I make it by using custom code.

```
Public Shared Status as String
Public Shared Value as Integer
  Public Shared Function GetValue(Item as Integer) as Integer
     if Status is nothing then 
        value=item
        status="1"
     else
     value= value - Item
      end if
     return Item
  End Function
  Public Shared Function GetTotal()
     return value
  End Function
```

Then call the function in Gross Profit cell:

=Code.GetValue(Sum(Fields!Trans_amount.Value))

To get the Net income, Call the function next to Gross Profit:

=Code.GetTotal()